# c# - Initialize List<> from another class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, class, oop

I have defined a class which has `List<>`. I have shortened my Code. It is too large. There are too many `List<>`& in `Method1()` there is lots of code. Here is my code :-

```
 public class Time : ITime
 {
        public List<Table1> Setts1 = new List<Table1>();
        public List<Tabl2> Setts2 = new List<Table2>();

        public void LoadSettings1(int companyId)
        {
            Setts1 = ctx.tblSett1.Where(a => a.CompanyId == companyId).Select(a => a).ToList();
        }



       public double Method1()
       {
          var data = Setts1.Where(m => m.SetType == "TYPE1").Select(m => m.Value1).FirstOrDefault();
          ......
          ......
       }

     }
```

I want to use `Method1()` in another class. My issue is `Setts1` which is preloaded in the `Time` Class. So when it is used in within the `Time` class it has `Records`. But when i call it from another class obviously `Setts1` will have no records. I tried to initialize it from another class like this :-

```
public class Class
{
   .....
   Time cls = new Time();
   cls.Setts1 = ....;
   cls.Method1();
}
```

But `Setts1` shows no records when in `Method1`. How to initialize the `List<>` from another class?

Comment: `Setts1` seems to be filled up inside method `LoadSettings1` and you haven't call this method inside your `Class` (last snippet in question). is that causing an issue?

Comment: I cannot call `LoadSettings1` from another class. So i want to initialize it from the calling class.

Comment: Why cannot call it? It is because you don't have the company id outside?

Comment: Because `LoadSettings1` has lots of another stuff which is not needed in another class. And there is not just one `List<>`, it has many. Code is more than 3000 lines.

Comment: If that's the situatoin than you have to figure out by yourself how to initialize your list as we cannot guess what other things are in your behemoth class.

Answer (score 2):

Exposing **field** members of a class, outside of the class is not a good practice. So I recommend using **properties** like this:

```
//Mark the field member as private
private List<Table1> _Setts1 = new List<Table1>();

//Use Property to access the field outside of the class
public List<Table1> Setts1
{
    get
    {
        if (_Setts1==null || _Setts1.Count()==0) //or any other logic you need
        {   
            //Initialize the field memeber
            _Setts1 = ctx.tblSett1.Where(a => a.CompanyId == companyId).Select(a => a).ToList();
        }

        return _Setts1
    }
}
```

This way you can forget about methods like `LoadSettings1` and it doesn't matter whether you use the `Setts` property inside the class or outside, it will be initialized at the right time.

Comment: He needs a constructor to initialize companyId too.

Comment: This is a pattern not an exact solution to his problem, as he said there are more than 3000 lines of code. so we can just say `ctx.tblSett1` has to be initialized before (e.g. in constructor). But according to his `LoadSettings1` it seems he's main concern is not that point and I recommend him for the rest of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call 'LoadSettings1(int companyId)'. This is the method which brings the records and populates your 'List'.

```
public class Class
{
    .....
   Time cls = new Time();
   cls.LoadSettings1(1);
   cls.Setts1 = ....;
   cls.Method1();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Something
{
   private Time cls = new Time();

   public Something(int companyId)
   {
      cls.LoadSettings1(companyId);
   }

   public void CallMethod1()
   {
      cls.Method1();
   }
}
```

Something like this? Using constructor for your "other class" to LoadSettings.

Answer (score 0):

```
cls.Setts1 = ....;
```

Actually I don't see how your code would not work, even if as Hossein said, it's bad practice. Look into how you're setting cls.Setts1 (the .... part). That's most probably the culprit